# Illegal String offset with multi-level json decode

Tags: php, json

I am having some issues trying to pull some data from a multi-level json url. I can get everything else except for a certain nested section.

```
{
  "name": "NewNationsPnW",
  "count": 10,
  "frequency": "Every 15 mins",
  "version": 31,
  "newdata": false,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Wed Jan 13 2016 22:57:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Wed Jan 13 2016 22:42:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "Nation": {
          "href": "https:\/\/politicsandwar.com\/nation\/id=30953",
          "text": "Renegade States"
        },
        "Founded": "01\/13\/2016",
        "Alliance": "None",
        "Continent": "North America",
        "property7": "",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "https:\/\/politicsandwar.com\/nations\/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The following code works to display that nested area but I would like to get it to individual outputs.

```
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/4p7k02r0?apikey=qAnUSnSVi8B17hie7xbPh9ijikNLzBzk";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$json = json_decode($response, true);

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($results);

foreach($json['results']['collection1'] as $stat) {
    foreach($stat['Nation'] as $stat1) {
        
            echo $stat1;

}
    if($stat['Alliance'] == 'None') {
    echo $stat['Founded'] . " - " . $stat['Alliance'] . " - " . $stat['Continent'] . "<br />";
}
}
```

I have tried the following

```
foreach($json['results']['collection1'] as $stat) {
    foreach($stat['Nation'] as $stat1) {
            echo $stat1['text'];
            echo $stat1['href'];
    }
    if($stat['Alliance'] == 'None') {
    echo $stat['Founded'] . " - " . $stat['Alliance'] . " - " . $stat['Continent'] . "<br />";
}
}
```

but I get

> Illegal string offset 'text' in parse.php on line 10
>
> Illegal string offset 'href' in parse.php on line 11

As well as it only displays

> hhRR01/13/2016 - None - North America
>
> hhFFhhDD01/13/2016 - None - Asia

I am sure I am doing something that is simple to fix but being a rookie, I am messing it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop is unnecessary, and the cause of your errors:

```
foreach($json['results']['collection1'] as $stat) {
    echo $stat['nation']['text'];
    echo $stat['nation']['href'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert a perfectly good JSON object data structure to an array.

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/4p7k02r0?apikey=qAnUSnSVi8B17hie7xbPh9ijikNLzBzk";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$j = json_decode($response );

foreach ($j->results->collection1 as $collection1 ) {
    echo $collection1->Nation->href;
    echo $collection1->Nation->text;

    if($collection1->Alliance == 'None') {
        echo sprintf("%s - %s - %s<br />",
                     $collection1->Founded,
                     $collection1->Alliance,
                     $collection1->Continent
                     );
    }
}
```